BASH: Assign values to variables with echo | sed | read
I'm trying to pass a string through a pipe going from echo to sed to read, but something isn't working:
#!/bin/bash

STR="alef|bet|gimel|daled"
echo $STR
echo $STR | sed 's/\|/ /g' | read ALPHA BETA GAMMA DELTA
echo "ALPHA = $ALPHA"
echo "BETA = $BETA"
echo "GAMMA = $GAMMA"
echo "DELTA = $DELTA"
# alef|bet|gimel|daled
# ALPHA = 
# BETA = 
# GAMMA = 
# DELTA =

The same thing happens if, on the third line, I use the statement:
echo $(echo $STR | sed 's/\|/ /g') | read ALPHA BETA GAMMA DELTA

The script works as you expect it to only if, on the third line, I use the statement:
read ALPHA BETA GAMMA DELTA <<< $(echo $STR | sed 's/\|/ /g')

When I use the first solution (that with the two pipes) shellcheck.net tells me that

Modification of ALPHA is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).

and that

ALPHA was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.

Does this mean that read cannot be used with the pipe and that the only way to assign a value to variables with read is to use the <<<?

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

If your string STR does not contain spaces or tabs: STR="alef|bet|gimel|daled"; set -- ${STR//|/ }; echo $1 $2 $3 $4

You can use read ALPHA BETA GAMMA DELTA <<<"$( echo $(echo $STR | sed 's/\|/ /g')" or more optimized read ALPHA BETA GAMMA DELTA <<<"$( sed 's/\|/ /g' <<< "STR" )" 

Have a look How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub That's fairly tangential here, as the OP wants to read multiple variables.

Indeed, read at the end of a pipe runs in a subprocess, which then immediately exits. The variables created by read disappear along with the shell subprocess where they were created.
You want
IFS='|' read -r alpha beta gamma delta <<<"$STR"

If you need this often, perhaps encapsulate this into a function.
split () {
    local IFS=$1
    shift
    read -r "$@"
}

Usage:
split '|' alpha beta gamma delta <<<"$STR"

If the IFS hack didn't remove the need for a substitution entirely, notice also that the parameter expansion ${STR//\|/ } would perform the substitution without the need for an external process.
Notice also Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization and When to wrap quotes around a shell variable? as well as the use of read -r to disable some unattractive legacy behaviors around backslashes. (You don't have any backslashes here, but it's probably a good routine to use -r always.)

The use of oldIFS is not safe.  See Bash Pitfalls #49 (OIFS="$IFS"; ...; IFS="$OIFS") and Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?.  One safe way to do it is IFS='|' read -r alpha beta gamma delta <<<"$STR".

You can use shell option lastpipe to run the last command of a pipeline in the  current shell environment.
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s lastpipe

STR="alef|bet|gimel|daled"
echo $STR
echo $STR | sed 's/[|]/ /g' | read ALPHA BETA GAMMA DELTA
echo "ALPHA = $ALPHA"
echo "BETA = $BETA"
echo "GAMMA = $GAMMA"
echo "DELTA = $DELTA"
# ALPHA = alef
# BETA = bet
# GAMMA = gimel
# DELTA = daled

This assumes job control is not active, which is usually the case when a script is run.

You should still quote "$STR". We have way too many examples of beginners copying code without quotes and then wondering why it doesn't work when there are minor changes in the input data.
